# Что не так с анимацией max-height

Tags: css, css-animation, keyframes

Почему анимация max-height происходит быстрее, чем другие свойства? Как это решить?

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.anim__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.anim__item__content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #ED6565;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #CAED65 0%, #65EDB4 100%);
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 40s animateHeight ease-in-out forwards;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #ED9E65;
}

@keyframes animateHeight {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 100000px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim__container">
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _анимация max-height происходит быстрее, чем другие свойства_?

Comment: @Grundy ой блиен, понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае, у Вас общая анимация для разных свойств с разными параметрами - такую анимацию проще написать, но настраивать намного труднее. Выход - разделить на несколько анимаций (в идеале, для каждого свойства) и перечислить их с раздельными параметрами в свойстве `animation`:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.anim__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.anim__item__content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #ED6565;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #CAED65 0%, #65EDB4 100%);
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 3s animateHeight ease-in-out forwards, 2s animateRotate ease-in-out forwards;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #ED9E65;
}

@keyframes animateHeight {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes animateRotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim__container">
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Конкретно по вопросу о скорости выполнения: анимация пытается уложиться в заданное время, поэтому, чем б**о**льшую высоту Вы зададите, тем быстрее будет скорость, так как нужно успеть пройти все итерации (кадры).

Comment: Как я вижу, адекатно анимировать неизвестную высоту можно только на JS

Comment: @МихаилКамахин: да, с JS-ом больше возможностей. Можно и без JS, но всё равно - где-то должны быть указаны чёткие размеры (в *px* или в *vh/vw*), чтобы было за что зацепится или от чего оттолкнуться другим элементам.